# Creating CSV file

Tags: c#, csv, export

using c#, open or reading a text file (source csv file) and . Finally, I have to create another csv file for these lines. Should I create a data table and insert each line after processing and finally export the data table to a csv file. OR Create a csv file before starting foreach {} and write to this csv file for each line.

How would you do it?

Comment: I'm lazy StreamWriter with a formatted WriteLine or if it's complicate LinqToCSV assembly

Comment: I think LinqToCSV requires .net 3.5 or above and I know the machine where they will be running this tool only has .net 2.0 framework. I will look into this. Thanks Kenny

Answer (score 1):

The stream way is definitely the way to go!

Although a few years old now - I've used this csv reader framework LumenWorks.Framework.IO.Csv  in a few projects and it has worked fine..

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/CsvReader.aspx

Comment: It's not really old. It's been updated last month to version 3.7.1.

Comment: Our company process to adopt new or open source framework is EXTREMELY discouraging, therefore, I wont be able to use this solution.

Comment: Probably best to go with a stream reader then if you cannot use this component. You can look at the code and take inspiration from what they have done as opposed to adding a reference to the component. The source code is available.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how big the orignal file is. In general, it helps scalability to stream like your 2nd option - to NOT load something completely into memeory if you don't really know how big it could be.

Comment: It could be 100 lines or 1000 lines.